# How to write a base64 video to file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, video, base64

My Express app is receiving a base64-encoded MP4 from the browser and writing it to a file. But the file isn't a valid video file, and the "file" utility simply identifies it as "data".

My Code:

```
const path = `${config.uploadPath}`;
const filename = `${uniqid()}.mp4`;

let base64Data = req.body.base64.replace(/^data:([A-Za-z-+/]+);base64,/, '');


fs.writeFileSync(`${path}${filename}`, base64Data, 'base64');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you sure there is a variable named `base64` is request response? If so, please try this code:

```
req.body.base64 = req.body.base64.replace(/^data:(.*?);base64,/, ""); // <--- make it any type
req.body.base64 = req.body.base64.replace(/ /g, '+'); // <--- this is important

fs.writeFile(`${path}${filename}`, req.body.base64, 'base64', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: It worked!!! 
can you explain whats is this? ->  req.body.base64 = req.body.base64.replace(/ /g, '+');

Comment: long story short... the way you are posting it, makes it being interpretated by express as urlencoded, so express tries to urldecode the given post data... that makes it invalid base64 string, as it changes all `+` signs to spaces (and base64 decoder expects `+` signs, not spaces), so that replaces those spaces back to `+` signs

Comment: @FlashThunder Will you care to solve a similar problem that I have : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58027135/node-js-video-file-created-from-buffer-is-unplayable